# Protect .Net Web API Query String

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, security, webapi

I have these .Net RESTFull GET APIs that contain query string.
Ex: https://my.api.com/employee/get?empId=123&uId=234&type=456

The security team of my customer tested my product. They dont want to expose the plain value of `empId` and `uId` query parameter when they inspect the nextwork tab in Chrome dev tool (press F12).

I used ajax to call these APIs from web client to .Net Web API Server.

How can I protect the query string parameter value? Which way to easy encode parameter from ajax calling and decode from API Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the answer, that is encrypt the querystrings. So basically you need to encrypt in js and decrypt in c#. You can use AES algorithm 
a sample is available [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/encrypt-in-javascript-and-decrypt-in-C-Sharp-with-aes-algorithm-i/)

Comment: This is the great answer which enough to my question. I will click on accept button but I have two more question. The first is the AES which run on javascript, the hacker can find the key to decrypt the parameter? The second is I implemented multipe APIs that has parameter in int, long, double,..., if I use AES, I must to update all of parameter to string type?

Comment: I hope its not too late, you should consider obfuscating your javascript. Though am no security expert.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.